# Pytorch Error: optimizer got an empty parameter list

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, valueerror

when I try to run pytorch tutorial code this Error appears:

```
ValueError: optimizer got an empty parameter list
```

this is my code:

```
class MultilayerpercePtron(nn.Module):

  def __init_(self,in_sz=784,out_sz=10,layers=[120,84]):

    super().__init__()

    self.fc1 = nn.linear(in_sz,layers[0])
    self.fc2= nn.linear(layers[0],layers[1])
    self.fc3 = nn.linear(layers[1],out_sz)
    
  def forward(self,x):
    
     x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
     x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
     x = self.fc3(x)
     return F.log_softmax(x,dim = 1)
torch.manual_seed(101)
model = MultilayerpercePtron()
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(),lr=0.001)
```

I run my code on colab however the basic code run on jupiter

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 mistakes:

1. it's `def __init__` not `def __init_`
2. It's `nn.Linear` not `nn.linear`